# Read a txt file with gets in C

Tags: c, arrays, gets

I want to know what is the best option to read a txt file that contain two line of numbers using gets function in c and save them in an array within 1 second.

Assume the following example as an txt file called ooo.txt and it has the number 2.000.000 in the first line (which will be the size of the array) and 2.000.000 number in the second line that will be stored in the array.

Eg

```
2000000
59 595 45 492 89289 5 8959 (+1.999.993 numbers)
```

code i try (only the fcanf function)

```
int t_size;
fscanf(fp, "%d",&t_size);  //bypass the first character!




        int* my_array = NULL; 
        my_array = malloc(t_size*sizeof(*my_array));


        if (my_array==NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
        return 1; //return with failure
        getchar();
        }

        int i =0;
        for ( i = 0; i < t_size; i++ )
        {
        fscanf(fp, "%d",&my_array[i]);  /*p[i] is the content of element at index i and &p[i] is the address of element at index i */
        }
```

best, so far, code to make the procedure in 1 second

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int is_end(char* input) {
        return *input == 0;
    }

    int is_linebreak(char* input) {
        return *input == '\r' || *input == '\n' || *input == ' ';
    }

    char* eat_linebreaks(char* input) {
        while (is_linebreak(input))
            ++input;

        return input;
    }

    size_t count_lines(char* input) {
        char* p = input;
        size_t rows = 1;

        if (is_end(p))
            return 0;

        while (!is_end(p)) {
            if (is_linebreak(p)) {
                ++rows;
                p = eat_linebreaks(p);
            }
            else {
                ++p;
            }
        }
        return rows;
    }

    /* split string by lines */
    char** get_lines(char* input, size_t line_count) {
        char* p = input;
        char* from = input;
        size_t length = 0;
        size_t line = 0;
            int i;
        char** lines = (char**)malloc(line_count * sizeof(char*));

        do {
            if (is_end(p) || is_linebreak(p)) {
                lines[line] = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
                for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
                    lines[line][i] = *(from + i);

                lines[line][length] = 0;
                length = 0;
                ++line;
                p = eat_linebreaks(p);
                from = p;

            }
            else {
                ++length;
                ++p;
            }
        } while (!is_end(p));

        // Copy the last line as well in case the input doesn't end in line-break
        lines[line] = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            lines[line][i] = *(from + i);

        lines[line][length] = 0;
        ++line;


        return lines;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        clock_t start;
        unsigned long microseconds;
        float seconds;
        char** lines;
        size_t size;
        size_t number_of_rows;
        int count;
        int* my_array;
        start = clock();

        FILE *stream;
        char *contents;
        int fileSize = 0;
            int i;

        // Open file, find the size of it
        stream = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_END);
        fileSize = ftell(stream);
        fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET);

        // Allocate space for the entire file content
        contents = (char*)malloc(fileSize + 1);

        // Stream file into memory
        size = fread(contents, 1, fileSize, stream);
        contents[size] = 0; 
        fclose(stream);

        // Count rows in content
        number_of_rows = count_lines(contents);

        // Get array of char*, one for each line
        lines = get_lines(contents, number_of_rows);

        // Get the numbers out of the lines
        count = atoi(lines[0]); // First row has count
        my_array = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            my_array[i] = atoi(lines[i + 1]);
        }

        microseconds = clock() - start;
        seconds = microseconds / 1000000.0f;
        printf("Took %fs", seconds);


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Use `fgets`. From the `gets` man-page: "BUGS: Never  use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use."

Comment: If you're reading numbers, you may be better off using `(f)scanf` instead.

Comment: Do you want to store them in a an array of "char *" or in an array of "int" ?

Comment: fscanf is slow for me. Except if you have any better code to offer. I want to store them in the best option ( i think it's array of int!)

Comment: `fscanf` isn't slow. You are probably doing other stuff like jumping around in the file or allocating too often. Show your code and we'll tell you.

Comment: Hmmm, looks okay. A problem I can see, though, is that you might have invalid input, i.e. something that doesn't parse as number. In that case `fscanf("%d", &x)` returns 0 (which you should check, as well as a potential `EOF`) and leaves `x` as it was. It also places the file offset where it was before reading. You will end up trying to parse the same invalid input over and over. A better approach might be to scan a string with `%s` and then use `strtol`.

Comment: check my second code to see if we can make it more simple using fscanf

Comment: Where did you get that from? It's about reading all lines in a file. Your file has only two lines: the first one with the count and the second one with the data. Your first code snipped looks basically good.  I still suspect wrong data. Print an error message if you hit invalid date, i.e. if `fscanf("%d", &x) < 1`.

Comment: ok but I have a question. Can I recreate the second code just to read 2 lines and get read all the other parts that we don't need? I worked for that a couple of days and i couldn't find the solution

Comment: 1 second is an eternity. Basically any method that you choose will be able to read two numbers in _way_ less than one second.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will want to use `fgets` instead to avoid dangerous buffer overflows.  Second, you want to remove all punctuation  from your numbers.  Thus 2.000.000 becomes 2000000.  Then you can use pointers and the `strtol` function to convert characters to integers; there are also other functions to convert to `float`s and other types.

Comment: no float numbers! strol would help me and I try it but I can't make the procedure fast enough. What should I try?

Comment: Why does it need to be so fast?  and how are you timing it?  You should also consider using `fopen`, `fread`, and `fclose`

Comment: of course I make such considerations. My employee told as to create this procedure in 1 second

Comment: how are you timing it?

Comment: I will update my code with another version I found on the internet and I use now. I also add the timing procedure.

Comment: I would just use `time` on Linux, it executes the specified program and times it.

Comment: no but your comment about 'time' help me a lot. Even though, I couldn't give more effort to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Since code wants speed and IO is a typically bottle-neck, reading the entire file at once after using `fstat()` to find its length ([@Charlon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27296799/2410359)) makes *some* sense.  Following is a quick parsing of that buffer.

```
    // Stream file into memory
    size = fread(contents, 1, fileSize, stream);
    contents[size] = 0; 
    fclose(stream);

    #if 1
    // new code

    size_t array_n;
    int n;
    if (sscanf(contents, "%zu%n", &array_n, &n) != 1) Handle_BadInput();

    my_array = malloc(array_n * sizeof *my_array);
    if (my_array == NULL) Handle_OOM();

    char *p = &contents[n];
    errno = 0;
    char *endptr;
    for (size_t count = 0; count < array_n; count++) {
      my_array[count] = strtol(p, &endptr, 10);
      if (p == endptr || errno) 
        Handle_BadInput();
      p = endptr;
    }

    char ch;
    if (sscanf(p, " %c", &ch) == 1) Handle_ExtraInput();

    #else
    //old code 

    // Count rows in content
    number_of_rows = count_lines(contents);

    // Get array of char*, one for each line
    lines = get_lines(contents, number_of_rows);

    // Get the numbers out of the lines
    count = atoi(lines[0]); // First row has count
    my_array = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
       my_array[i] = atoi(lines[i + 1]);
    }
   #endif
```

Still prefer the scale-able approach of reading one number at a time.

Comment: Ok i get errors. Can you please write all the code? Is that code for my 2nd version? I don't need any error handling functions.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas Please provide detail on "i get errors".  This is for the 2nd version.  Are you using a C99 or later compiler?

Comment: yes I use gcc -std=c99 option. Also I couldn't update my second code with yours (it seems that I can't find the right place to)

Comment: @GeorgeGkas BTW: Suggest adding a clock check between reading the file and parsing the file.  This will help show IO versus parsing time bottle-necks.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas If this the first time in the loop?  Sure `malloc()` succeeded?  Since you mentioned "I don't need any error handling functions", I am concerned code is stuck on something simple.  All warnings enabled?

Comment: @GeorgeGkas Face-palm: I have 2 `count++;`.  Need to drop 1.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas What is the declaration for `children`?

Comment: @GeorgeGkas What are the values of `array_n` and `n`?

Comment: false numbers! The problem is there. something with sscanf

Comment: @GeorgeGkas  Idea for the future: "I don't need any error handling functions" may be true for the assignment, but for development, it saves times.  Suggest not speeding through development without incorporating error checking.  At least, code can use a liberal amount of `assert()`.

Comment: well don't forget that we have declare a char with 0 value contents[size] = 0;

Comment: @GeorgeGkas This answer did not change memory allocation nor initialization for `contents` so I am not sure how your comment applies.

Comment: so my best choise so far is my second code as it is. Hmm :wondering:

Comment: @GeorgeGkas I will delete my half of this discussion in a bit, if you do not mind.  OK?  Once you get to 15+ reps, these discussions can be done in chat rooms.

Comment: οκ but I am bit dissapointed...(I couldn't update my second code)

Comment: for 2 reasons. 1st) i'm new at C programming and I took the long way to write the function, which is correct but not very readable. 2nd) I use many pointers which also make the functions non readable. So i have lost inside my CODE! -.-

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way needs a lot of RAM :

1) open the file (man open)

2) use the fstat function to get the size of you file (man fstat)

3) read the file with a buffer malloc-ed with the size you just get at 2) (man malloc)

4) close the file (man close)

5) parse your buffer and transform each block of digits (each time until ' ' or '\0') to int

EDIT : if your RAM is not enough large, you need to create a get_next_int function that only stores in your buffer the next number in the file

EDIT 2 : You can read until you know the number of int you will need to store and compares this number with a security coef to the size of your ram, and use the good way so that your program won't set errno to ENOMEM if you know what I'm talking about ;)

Comment: Hmmm. If I've understood correctly, all 2,000,000 numbers are in a single line. Also, what's the benefit of slurping the whole file when you convert the data to `int`s anyway? If the data were strings, okay, but in tis case, there's no need to keep the whole file contents in memory.

Comment: I was misunderstanding, you're right, I updated my answer, check it out :)